# How do i refer to this element with Selenium (python)?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

So i'm trying to automate this simple thing, where i want to click on a image.
Here is HTML:

```
<div class="guild-inner" draggable="false" style="border-radius: 15px;">
<a draggable="false" class="avatar-small" href="/channels/223259649967652887/381675339702599690" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/223259649967652887/2be8d9ec8759056fabe8caa306c632c8.png&quot;);">
</a>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
def find_tc():
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/channels/223259649967652887/381675339702599690"]').click()
wait(5)
```

Here is the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[href="/channels/223259649967652887/381675339702599690"]"}
```

I have to refer this by href because that is the only thing that is unique. All the images are dynamically defined so i also can't refer to the image by on which number it is.Thanks in advance! (new to selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is that i was trying to find the element when the page is not completely loaded. So i had to put like one minute sleep time before initiating the search for the element..because the java script is still being loaded in the background. Still is there any was to decide if the page has been completely loaded including java script instead of putting a random sleep time? happy to learn!